# asp.net mvc ckeditor image upload error User does not have sufficient privileges

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ckeditor

I'm using visual studio 2013 
I'm installing ckeditor from NuGet
and installing MB.FileBrowser from NuGet
and add

```
 config.filebrowserBrowseUrl = 'http:/FileBrowser/FileBrowser.aspx?type=files';
 config.filebrowserImageBrowseUrl = 'http:/FileBrowser/FileBrowser.aspx?type=images';
 config.filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl = '/FileBrowser/FileBrowser.aspx?type=flash';
```

to config.js in ckeditor

and change DefaultAccessMode to Write in filebrowser.aspx

every thing work ok
but when I upload an image or drag it, give me error

> User does not have sufficient privileges.

how to solve this?is there another way?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to the place where you have your website
2. Check out for the folder where you are saving the images
3. Click on read/write mode, this will enable you the read the files as
   we as write files into the folder Please find [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727008.aspx) where you can find how to give read/write rights to folder
4. Then try debugging your application

**Update**

As well as read **Granting access** section on [this](http://filebrowser.magiccms.org/Docs.aspx) link

Comment: thanks for your reply 
i try for folder property and make it full control but not work
i read Granting access  where is MB.FileBrowser.MagicSession.Current.FileBrowserAccessMode
i search but not found

Comment: Ohhh what error you are getting ?? Access denied ??

Comment: User does not have sufficient privileges